# I am trying to implement crud operations on a table,where I select the FK data from a dropdownlist.I get a NullReference Exception when I try to save

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model

My models are:

```
public class Presentation
{
    public int PresentationId { get; set; }
    public string PresentationTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime PresentationTime { get; set; }
    public Level? Level { get; set; }
    public virtual Professor Professor { get; set; }
}

public class Professor
{
    public int ProfessorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Presentation> Presentations { get; set; }
}
```

`Level` is an `enum`, forget about it for now. I have a web page where I try to add a new `Presentation`. This means I am adding a `title`,`time`,`level` and a `professor`. The `professor` is added through a `DropDownList`.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     drpProfessor.DataSource = db.Professors.ToList();
     drpProfessor.DataTextField = "Name";
     drpProfessor.DataValueField = "ProfessorId";
     drpProfessor.DataBind();
}
```

The `DropDownList` is populated with the names, but on Save action I get a `NullReference` Exception. Save looks like this:

```
Presentation newPres = new Presentation();
newPres.PresentationTitle = txtPresentationTitle.Text;
newPres.Level = ParseEnum<Level>(drpLevel.SelectedValue);
newPres.PresentationTime = calendar.SelectedDate;
newPres.Professor.ProfessorId = Convert.ToInt32(drpProfessor.SelectedItem.Value);

db.Presentations.Add(newPres);
db.Entry(newPres).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;

db.SaveChanges();
litMsg.Text = "New presentation added!";
```

Please ignore again the `Level`,it's working fine. But the error is at:

```
newPres.Professor.ProfessorId = Convert.ToInt32(drpProfessor.SelectedItem.Value);
```

I am trying to add the value (`ProfessorId`) of the selected item to db, but I get:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I checked and the value(`ProfessorId`) is selected from the `DropDownList`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: most likely newPres.Professor is NULL.

Comment: View it in the debugger and it will tell you exactly which variable is null. We can only guess.

Comment: From the initialization of `Presentation`, I see no where `Professor` could be init first before its `ProfessorId` is set. Your best bet is include the foreign key in the class `Presentation` and set the `ProfessorId` directly without having to access via `Professor`.

Comment: Try drpProfessor.SelectedValue instead of  drpProfessor.SelectedItem.Value. I'm not sure... May be it helps...

Comment: @SankarRaj I think it's the same, maybe remove `Value`, just keep `SelectedItem`, the Value is already set to `ProfessorId` part. `SelectedItem` would be `Professor`.

Comment: @Hopeless it might be same... But since selected item is a dropdownlist item, How can we assign it to the property or method?

Comment: @SankarRaj I'm not sure about ASP.NET, in WPF it should be a `Professor`. If so we have no way to get access to the actual item (which is a `Professor`). As you see he already set `drpProfessor.DataValueField = "ProfessorId"` - that means `SelectedValue` should be `ProfessorId` and if `SelectedItem` is just a wrapper dropdownlist item, its `Value` should be the same as `SelectedValue`.

Comment: The value is selected,and the id is returned, but what I don't get is what's wrong with the declaration of Professor, or the relationship is not right? I know what can cause the exception,but I don't know how else to try to fix this.

Comment: @Hopeless - You are right, Professor is null, but how I should use ProfessorId directly from Presentation?

Comment: @user3399858 as I said, if possible you should add a foreign property `ProfessorId` to the `Presentation` class, then instead of setting `Professor`, use `ProfessorId`. If you cannot do that, you need to fetch the `Professor` from its Id, e.g: `newPres.Professor = db.Professor.Find(Convert.ToInt32(drpProfessor.SelectedItem.Value));`